# gluster peer probe glusterx - returns request timedout

Tags: ubuntu, glusterfs

I am trying to setup a 2-node gluster server.  I have installed gluster-server in both these nodes and have started the glusterd service.
I am able ping each of these machines from both machines.
After this, when I try to execute the command

```
sudo gluster peer probe gluster1
```

This is the error that I received

```
Error : Request timed out
```

Answer (score 3):

So I experienced the same issue when trying to configure gluster on a 3 node Ubuntu t3-small cluster in AWS.

What worked for me is
opening TCP ports 24007:24008 and 49152:49156 within aws for the nodes.

In my case we use terraform to provision the nodes so the aws_security_group would have a config:

```
  ingress {
    from_port   = 24007
    to_port     = 24008
    protocol    = "tcp"
    cidr_blocks = ["0.0.0.0/0"]
  }
  ingress {
    from_port   = 49152
    to_port     = 49156
    protocol    = "tcp"
    cidr_blocks = ["0.0.0.0/0"]
  }
  ingress {
    from_port   = 38465
    to_port     = 38467
    protocol    = "tcp"
    cidr_blocks = ["0.0.0.0/0"]
  }
  ingress {
    from_port   = 111
    to_port     = 111
    protocol    = "tcp"
    cidr_blocks = ["0.0.0.0/0"]
  }
  ingress {
    from_port   = 111
    to_port     = 111
    protocol    = "udp"
    cidr_blocks = ["0.0.0.0/0"]
  }
  ingress {
    from_port   = 2049
    to_port     = 2049
    protocol    = "tcp"
    cidr_blocks = ["0.0.0.0/0"]
  }
```

Additionally I had to expose the ports locally running these commands in each of the nodes

```
sudo iptables -A INPUT -m state --state NEW -m tcp -p tcp --dport 24007:24008 -j ACCEPT
sudo iptables -A INPUT -m state --state NEW -m tcp -p tcp --dport 49152:49156 -j ACCEPT
sudo iptables -A INPUT -m state --state NEW -m tcp -p tcp --dport 38465:38467 -j ACCEPT
sudo iptables -A INPUT -m state --state NEW -m tcp -p tcp --dport 111:111 -j ACCEPT
sudo iptables -A INPUT -m state --state NEW -m tcp -p tcp --dport 2049:2049 -j ACCEPT
```

Some references for how I landed at this:

https://serverfault.com/questions/571386/firewall-iptables-rules-for-glusterfs
https://docs.rackspace.com/support/how-to/allow-web-traffic-in-iptables/

[Ports](https://docs.gluster.org/en/release-3.7.0-1/Troubleshooting/troubleshootingFAQ/)

Hope that helps

Comment: Thanks, i am using Oracle Cloud Infrastructure OCI, ant since i add the 24007 port ingress rule and openning ports in nodes everything worked flowentky

Answer (score 0):

This got resolved. gluster used 24007 port to communicate among the peers of a storage volume. I had to specify a firewall rule to accept incoming tcp requests through 24007 from other machine

Answer (score 0):

Yes You should add this frewall rule  :

> on Centos or red hat distribution

```
firewall-cmd --add-service=glusterfs --permanent
success
firewall-cmd --reload
```

> for ubuntu :

```
ufw allow glusterfs
```